# window.onerror does not catch all errors

Tags: browser, error-handling

For some reason I am able to catch all of the console errors except for "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL". Does anyone know why that error is filtered?

my code:

```
window.onerror = function(message) { alert(message); return true; };
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

> **Possible duplicate:**
>
> - [Display Javascript "same origin policy" violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270637/display-javascript-same-origin-policy-violations)
> - [Catching same origin exception in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318658/catching-same-origin-exception-in-javascript)

I am not sure if that's the way to detect [Same origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) violations, since the `window.onerror` only catches *runtime JS errors* (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror)).

For cross browser compatibility of `error` event you can check this out:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Comment: Thanks Yan, I am testing in Chrome. Regarding the code, it's just an Iframe that is producing the error I wish to catch...

Comment: Hey @Gidon , I just edited the answer. Hope I could've helped you.