# Detect denied access to iframe url

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I am trying to check the url of an iframe, but I just realized that I don't need the actual url, just information of whether the url is within my own domain or not.

I figured I could use

```
document.getElementById("frameid").documentWindow.location.href
```

and it will return an error if the url is not within my domain. But how do I intercept this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213943/window-onerror-does-not-catch-all-errors/16214094#16214094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post in the comment I got was helpful, but I did not find the post on my own, so I thought I'd post my final solution here in case somebody else comes here with a similar question.

```
$('#iFrame').on('load', function () {
    try {
        // checks if iframe content is internal
        test = this.contentWindow.document.location.href;
        showIframe = false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        // if an error is thrown, iframe content is external
        showIframe = true;
    }

    if (showIframe) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```